# String to array to multidimensional hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, hash

I don't really know if the title is correct, but the question is quite simple:

I have a value and a key.

The key is as follows:

`"one.two.three"`

Now, how can I set this hash:

`params['one']['two']['three'] = value`

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate; look hard on the site and you'll find more answers.

Comment: Your comment would be useful if it included a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it with this code:

```
keys = "one.two.three".split '.' # => ["one", "two", "three"]
params = {}; value = 1; i = 0;  # i is an index of processed keys array element
keys.reduce(params) { |hash, key|
    hash[key] = if (i += 1) == keys.length
      value # assign value to the last key in keys array
    else
      hash[key] || {} # initialize hash if it is not initialized yet (won't loose already initialized hashes)
    end
}
puts params # {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>1}}}
```

Comment: Looks good, was hoping for a one liner, but this will work.. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim. No need for one-liners, just create an abstraction `Hash#set_from_path(path, value)` written with good, clear, maintenable code.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

```
def make_hash(keys)
  keys.empty? ? 1 : { keys.shift => make_hash(keys) }
end

puts make_hash("one.two.three".split '.')
# => {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>1}}}
```

Comment: this is ok to create a new hash, but I thought the OP wanted to update an existing hash...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inject` method:

```
key = "one.two.three"
value = 5

arr = key.split(".").reverse
arr[1..-1].inject({arr[0] => value}){ |memo, i| {i => memo} }
# => {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>5}}}
```

Comment: So can I make this a one liner like so: `hash = key.split(".").reverse[1..-1].inject({arr[0] => value}){ |memo, i| {i => memo}}` ?

Comment: +Tim, `arr` is not defined in your one liner

Comment: `"one.two.three".split('.').reverse.inject(5) { |x, y| { y => x } }` outputs 
`=> {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>5}}}`

Comment: That looks very nice, but how can I  do it on an existing hash ?

Comment: This is so elegant, it should be the accepted answer!